# Is there a simple to know if my connection string is encrypt or not?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, connection-string

I want to know if my connection string is encrypted or not. I don't want to encrypt it again and again. This is only an issue in development stage. Any way to check the status of the connection string in App.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not see if the connection string contains the strings "Source" or "Catalog" (case insensitive)? If so, it is not encrypted. This sure is simple ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Look for the dbname or the likes - you won't find it if it's encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the best solution to just check the SectionInformation.IsProtected property?

This is detailed on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.isprotected.aspx) and Jon Galloway has a post, [Encrypting Passwords in a .NET app.config File](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx), about this as well if you'd like a longer example (some tweaking required).

Comment: No, because only that setting might be encrypted and not the whole section. What if I want to find out if only a particular setting is encrypted or not? Or to make the question more general, **is there a simple way to find out whether the contents of a string var are encrypted or not?**

Thanx

Comment: Hi Pap. Good question. I'd recommend asking this as a question on SO.